# NTFS: What is a file?

Tags: ntfs

Today, i discovered that [the Master File Table is itself a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230(v=vs.85).aspx).  However, I guess that file doesn't have a path, you cannot open, delete, or modify it.  So if that is a file,  maybe partitions are files, too?  What defines an NTFS file?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file

Comment: The MFT is an "NT object" in the NT Object Manager. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_the_Windows_NT_operating_system_line#Executive)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134(v=ws.10).aspx explains a lot.
Do you have a specific goal that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

The path to the MFT is `\$Mft` - the mirror is `\$MftMirr`.  Windows prevents you from listing, opening, or modifying them while it is running, but they are visible if you look at the volume under some tools (such as EnCase).

The NTFS documentation refers to them as "[metafiles](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-ebook/ntfs-file-system-metafiles.htm)."  The names of them are less important to Windows than the position they occupy in the file table (i.e. `$Mft` is file No. 1 on the disk) - which makes sense because Windows cannot locate files by name without the content of the metafiles, so there is probably deep in the NTFS API a way to access files by file number only (sort of like opening a file in Linux by "inode" number instead of name).

Comment: Why does Windows not prevent EnCase from listing those files?

Comment: You can't look at a live mounted volume with EnCase (AFAIK, been a long time since I've played with it), but it will display those files on a captured image or offline drive.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I guess that file doesn't have a path, you cannot open, delete, or modify it.

You can call ReadFile() and give it the filename *$MFT*. O

> What defines an NTFS file?

Technically, a stream of bits. So everything on a disk, including the boot sector is a **file**.
A partition isn't really a file though.  You don't really open a partition per se, but a file in the partition.

I'll quote Microsoft here:

> All file system data, including the system bootstrap code and directories, are stored by the NTFS file system in files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364056(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Psst!  [One **can** open a partition as a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#Physical_Disks_and_Volumes).  Keep this confusing datum under your hat, though, because it doesn't relate to on-disc NTFS structures.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP: That doesn't return a file handle. Those are calls directly to the device driver.

Comment: It does return a file handle. It's the only (non-error) thing that it _can_ return, indeed. You'll be onto a loser trying to find ways of redefining _handles_ to I/O Manager _file_ objects as somehow not being _file handles_. The area where the distinction lies is where I've already pointed it out: the on-disc NTFS data structures. But don't breathe too hard, lest someone notice that the question and answers here talk about things that can be opened and modified, which of course one can do with partitions by opening them as files.

Comment: Also don't forget that in NTFS a file can actually be one or more streams of bits - you can have multiple or "alternate" streams.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simplistic view as NTFS has been extended with Journaling, etc.

**Partitions** are entries in a table that define areas of the disk to be used for volumes. They are data structures that live **outside** the file system and are used by BIOS and the OS to structure how things are stored on the disk.

**NTFS volumes** contain a Master File Table at the core of the NTFS file system. It is a file that the operating system opens and uses to structure storage and store metadata about the files the volume contains. Each file on the disk has a record entry in the Master File Table and if small enough, live entirely within the MFT.

Larger files are Extents that the file record entry points to.

Directories are files that contain index information about file record entries and if small enough, also live entirely within the MFT.

Due to the fact that small files may entirely live in the MFT and that there may be many files and directories in the volume, the MFT may also be fragmented to increase its storage space (unlike FAT which was limited to a certain preset area).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS